# Redirect to incorrect URL, Kohana 3.0.9

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-3.0

iam trying add the multilangual in kohana 3.0.9, and when iam enter in browser link like, http://site-name.com/en/, it redirect to http://site-name.com//en/en

Answer (score 0):

In Kohana multi language means put all your text in seperate files as en-en.php or de-de.php in the i18n directory.. from your application or module

The first magic is in the bootstrap !  Setting the language and ready

No redirects....